# Java Web App - cannot edit database despite the connection works

Tags: java, mysql, database, jakarta-ee, web

I'm creating java web application using maven.
I added mySQL local database as a datasource and when I'm testing connection everything is ok however when I start the app and try to add a new record it doesn't work, I mean code is executing and app is working but there is no new data in database. I also cannot check if there is some data in database. There is no error or anything but other instructions not conneted to database work properly.
In my web.xml I've got

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/DSTestPool</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

In jetty.xml

```
<New id="DSTestPool" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg></Arg>
        <Arg>jdbc/DSTestPool</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
                <Set name="driverClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</Set>
                <Set name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/psi3</Set>
                <Set name="username">root</Set>
                <Set name="password"></Set>
                <Set name="maxTotal">100</Set>
                <Set name="maxIdle">30</Set>
                <Set name="minIdle">10</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
```

and I'm creating user like this

```
public class UsersDAO {
    private DataSource ds;
    public UsersDAO(DataSource ds) {
        this.ds = ds;
    }
    public void createUser(User user){
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        try {
            con = ds.getConnection("root","");
            String sql="insert into users (Username,Password,Valid) values(?,?,?)";
            pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, user.getLogin());
            pst.setString(2, user.getPassMD5());
            pst.setInt(3,1);
            pst.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            DbTools.closeQuietly(pst, con);
        }
    }
}
```

my datasources.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="DataSourceManagerImpl" format="xml" hash="4078573267">
    <data-source source="LOCAL" name="MySQL - psi3@localhost" uuid="c2a621c7-089c-4d40-9767-1387f9bfb343">
      <driver-ref>mysql</driver-ref>
      <synchronize>true</synchronize>
      <jdbc-driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</jdbc-driver>
      <jdbc-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/psi3</jdbc-url>
      <driver-properties>
        <property name="zeroDateTimeBehavior" value="convertToNull" />
        <property name="tinyInt1isBit" value="false" />
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="utf8" />
        <property name="characterSetResults" value="utf8" />
        <property name="yearIsDateType" value="false" />
      </driver-properties>
      <libraries />
    </data-source>
  </component>
</project>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>psi_java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>psi_java</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jettyVersion>9.2.5.v20141112</jettyVersion>
    </properties>



    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jettyVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
<!-- This plugin is needed for the servlet example -->
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jettyVersion}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <jettyXml>
                            ${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty.xml
                    </jettyXml>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.34</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I've tried a few things but nothing seems to work, test shows that connection is ok and I do not know what to do with that. I wrote some apps in java but it's my first time with java web and I have no idea what to do with that so I will be grateful if someone can help me.
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3.

Comment: try to add records directly from a your mysql client, see what happens

Comment: why do you declare a JNDI name in your jetty.xml and some similar information in the datasources.xml ?
and for my information, which framework read datasource.xml ? is it ext.js ?

Comment: @aurelius I've already tried to add records from my client and it works.

Comment: @vincent to be honest I don't know, my profesor gave as a template of it and I'm working on it I don't know how it exactly works I'm trying to understand it but like I said it's my first time with java web so I still don't understand many things.

Comment: which frameworks do you use on your project ?

Comment: I do not see any frameworks here

Comment: @Meii, post your `pom.xml`

Comment: I added it to my post.

Comment: I think that ds.getConnection() may not work properly but I don't know why and how to fix it.